# Hide DIV or button based on query result

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to hide a DIV or the pertaining button based on a value stored in the session (which gathers user data on login). For example, if someone logs in with the access code of 20, I want certain buttons to be disabled, hidden, etc. This is an internal portal with beginner users using it, so I'm thinking simple. Any other ideas are more than welcome. How can I do this?

Here is my current code. I've removed the style attributes for the post. Thanks all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>MK Diamond - Main Menu</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<?php 
include("session.php");
echo "<body style=\"background-attachment: fixed; background-image: url('img/background.jpg');\">";
echo "<div class=\"auto-style1\" style=\"height: 213px; width: 100%; float: left;\">";
echo "<span class=\"auto-style5\">";
echo "<span class=\"auto-style22\"><strong>This portal is for MK Diamond use&nbsp;"; 
echo "only. Any and all access is monitored and controlled - unauthorized&nbsp;"; 
echo "attempts will be investigated.</strong></span><br>";
echo "<img src=\"img/mk-logo.png\" height=\"185\" width=\"375\"/></span><br>";
echo "</div>";
echo  "<div>";
echo    "<table style=\"width: 65%\" align=\"center\" class=\"auto-style7\">";
echo    "<tr>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style21\" style=\"height: 24px\"></td>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style21\" style=\"height: 24px; width: 25px;\">&nbsp;</td>";
echo    "</tr>";
echo    "<tr>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style18\" style=\"height: 24px\">";
echo    "<input name=\"jobsbutton\" type=\"button\" value=\"M.S. Jobs Menu\" onclick=\"location.href='jobsmenu.php'\" style=\"width:160px; height: 35px\"  /></td>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style18\" style=\"height: 24px; width: 25px;\">&nbsp;</td>";
echo    "</tr>";
echo    "<tr>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px\">";
echo    "<input name=\"ordersbutton\" ID=\"ordersbutton\" type=\"button\" value=\"B.V. Orders Menu\" onclick=\"location.href='ordersmenu.php'\" style=\"width: 160px; height: 35px\" />";
echo    "</td>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px; width: 25px;\">";
echo    "&nbsp;</td>";
echo    "</tr>";
echo    "<tr>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px\">";
echo    "&nbsp;</td>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px; width: 25px;\">";
echo    "&nbsp;</td>";
echo    "</tr>";
echo    "<tr>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px\">";
echo    "</td>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px; width: 25px;\">";
echo    "</td>";
echo    "</tr>";
echo    "<tr>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px\">";
echo    "You are logged in as&nbsp;"; echo "$row[name]";
echo    "</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a></td>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px; width: 25px;\">";
echo    "</td>";
echo    "</tr>";
echo    "<tr>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style23\" style=\"height: 24px\">";
echo    "Security Class:&nbsp;"; echo "$row[acctype]";
echo    "</td>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px; width: 25px;\">";
echo    "</td>";
echo    "</tr>";
echo    "<tr>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px\">";
echo    "<strong>Welcome to the Main Menu</strong></td>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px; width: 25px;\">";
echo    "&nbsp;</td>";
echo    "</tr>";
echo    "<tr>";
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px\">";
echo    "<input name=\"Button1\" type=\"button\" value=\"Release Notes\" onclick=\"location.href='releasenotes.php'\" style=\"width: 160px; height: 35px\" />";
echo    "</td>";    
echo    "<td class=\"auto-style19\" style=\"height: 24px; width: 25px;\">";
echo    "&nbsp;</td></tr>";
echo    "</table>";
?>
</div>
<div class="auto-style8">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just because people are old doesn't mean they don't know how to go into developer tools and unhide/undisable a button... they need to not be in the DOM to begin with

Comment: `if ($row[acctype] == 20) { echo "<button>"; }`.

Comment: Take a look at [`heredoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax, it will make your code a lot neater.

Comment: Whatever this is doing `include("session.php");` it should be placed at the very top of the script before anything is outputed to the rendered document, that is, if it contains a `session_start()`.